# How to dynamically get typeof ()

Tags: c#

I'm using this code to get a specific property from my class `Index`

```
_PropertyInfo info = typeof (IndexViewModel).GetProperty("Header");
```

Can I somehow use the `typeof ()` -part and get the type dynamically by passing in a string? My example below shows what I'm trying to do.

```
string model = "IndexViewModel";
_PropertyInfo info = typeof (model).GetProperty("Header");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) method to obtain `Type` instance for given string.But be aware that the method expects an [assembly qualified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx) name.It means you need to pass namespace + type name. For example `Type.GetType("String")` returns *null* but `Type.GetType("System.String")` returns the type of `string` class. Ofcourse the *assembly qualified* name is not just about namespace + type name, refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx) to find out more.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I'm trying to do it like this, but gets null: `var ok = Type.GetType("IndexViewModel");` Could you please give me a example of it?

Comment: @user3228992 what is the namespace of IndexViewModel ?

Comment: then try it like this: `Type.GetType("MyNotes.IndexViewModel");`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the fully-qualified name, you can loop through assemblies to find the type like this:

```
public static Type GetType(string typeName)
  {
    var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

    foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
      {
        var allTypes = assembly.GetTypes();
        var type = allTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == typeName);
        if (type != null)
          {
             return type;
          }
      }

    throw new KeyNotFoundException("Can't find type");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use Type.GetType method